# TDD - How to test .Read() without .Write()?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

We're trying to use TDD to create our system and we've come to a situation where we can't figure out what the right TDD course of action is.

We've hidden the file IO behind an interface like so:

```
public interface IFileIo
{
    byte[] Read(string fileName);
    void Write(string filename, byte[] data);
}
```

and now we're creating an `InMemoryFileIo` that we can use in place of the real `SystemFileIo` class that we'll use for production.

We want to make sure this `InMemoryFileIo` works correctly and there may be cases where we want to use it in lieu of the actual file system, so it should be "production quality".

The question is, doing everything the "right TDD way", how can we create a test for either `.Read()` or `.Write()` where they don't depend on each other?

In order to test that `.Read()` worked correctly, we would have needed to successfully made a call to `.Write()` first, and similarly, to test that `.Write()` works correctly we would then need to call `.Read()` afterwards. By doing this, we've actually created the same test twice (arrange, then a write, then a read, then asserts).

Lets say we have two tests, one that tests `.Read()` and one that tests `.Write()`. If either of those functions doesn't work, then both tests fail. This violates the principle that "A test should only have one reason to fail".

The example here is for file IO, but this same question has come up for us when working with a database (test `put` without `get`).

Comment: That's fine in this case, just test them together - a failure at one would mean the other one is failing too anyway and the error message in the test will tell you which one failed anyway in cases you can find out. Don't overthink it and don't be tempted to use any mock-reflection thingies that lie - it's within the same unit here and it makes sense.

Comment: The "proper" way (which again, don't worry about it) would be for InMemoryFileIo to take a `byte[]`  in its constructor instead of creating it (dependency injection) which would allow you to pre-set the data to be read or run checks on the data written externally to each other - really though, don't overthink this - just write tests that make sense to you and help identify defects in the system clearly.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that if your in-memory IO class is just used as a test double, it should be simple enough to not warrant a bunch of testing. the point is having a fake for other classes you are TDDing that depend on the interface right? coupling their passing or not passing a test to whether or not your in-memory file IO fake is bug-free seems like a potentially bad idea to me. I suggest keeping your stubs dead simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole question comes down to how exactly you define your "units". For me personally, it helps to think of a "unit" as a coherent set of behaviour rather than a single method invocation.

[Roy Osherove](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) defines a unit as:

> A unit test is an automated piece of code that invokes a unit of work in the system and then checks a single assumption about the behavior of that unit of work. A unit of work is a single logical functional use case in the system that can be invoked by some public interface (in most cases). A unit of work can span **a single method, a whole class or multiple classes working together** to achieve one single logical purpose that can be verified.

So in the end, throwing all guidelines aside, if it does not make sense to split up reading/writing responsibilities for you just test them in combination. In general, when I feel like there is no clean/easy way to verify the results of a test through a backdoor (be it a collaborator that can be mocked, some state verification,...), I have no problems with exercising some other functionality of the public API. These tests that exercise your components through their public API's tend to be less brittle than the ones that use a backdoor for verification anyway.